# How to upsert a LookUp field via the REST API?

Tags: lookup, upsert

I have a field that's called `AccountName` and it's a LookUp field. When i try to update it with plain text, i get an error:

`id value of incorrect type, errorCode:MALFORMED_ID`

How can i upsert a LookUp field?

EDIT:

I just send a request to the REST API (using `patch`) with a `JSON` object with the following field:
`AccoutName: "someName"`

Comment: can you add your code here

Comment: Done. Nothing out of the ordinary - the normal request with a `JSON` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a lookup field so you need to pass the AccountId instead of name.

```
AccoutName: "001........."
```

**Update based on comments**

Upsert works based on Id value.

If you need to check if Account with name already exists then you have to write a separate logic to find the accounts and then pass those accountId.

SOQL logic will be like this:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE Name =:<AccountName>
```

Comment: Got it, but what if i want to do an upsert by AccountName? What if i want to say "if an account with this name doesn't exist, create it. if it does, do nothing"

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer!
Can a LookUp field be an external ID? Because i know you could do upsert that way too right?

Comment: External Id cannot be a lookup field